# How to define the type of a prop, which is a functional component while specifying the FC's various prop types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have two functional components which have two different prop types.

```ts
export interface OrderImageProps {
    orders: ICartItem[]
}

const OrderImage: React.FC<OrderImageProps> = (props: OrderImageProps) => {
    return (
        <div>
            // show some list
        </div>
    );
};
```

and

```ts
export interface ProductImageProps {
    src: string
}

const ProductImage: React.FC<ProductImageProps> = (props: ProductImageProps) => {
    return (
        <Image className='img-fluid admin-product-image' src={props.src}/>
    );
};
```

These two components are entities of a table, but conditionally rendered. So I need to pass these two components to the table component.

```ts
interface CustomDataTableProps {
    nameTag: string
    itemTag: string
    priceTag: string
    categoryTag: string
    dateTag: string
    actionsTag: string
    image: React.FC<ProductImageProps | OrderImageProps>
    list: boolean
}
    
const CustomDataTable: React.FC<CustomDataTableProps> = (props: CustomDataTableProps) => {
    const cartItems: ICartItem[] = useSelector((state: RootState): ICartItem[] => (state.cart.cartItems));
    const sampleData = sampleProducts.map((product: ICartItem) => {

    return {
        image: React.createElement(props.image, props.list ?
        {
            orders: cartItems
        } :
        {
            src: product.src
        }),
        // more data are in here
    };
}
```

But when passing props to the `CustomDataTable`, it shows `FC<ProductImageProps> is not assignable to type FC<ProductImageProps | OrderImageProps>`.

I understand this error, clearly they are incompatible types.

From my understanding may be these props need an `XOR` behavior on `React.FC<>` type.

This can easily be done by providing a `render prop` on `CustomDataTable`. Also there are other table entities which have like this kind of conditionally rendered components.

Can my first approach be achieved or is it better if I use a render prop?

Comment: Just curious, would this work? `image: React.FC<ProductImageProps> | React.FC<OrderImageProps>`

Comment: Will the table contain both of these at the same time or have EITHER all items of the first type OR the second type? The above comment should solve things

Comment: @GulamHussain that doesn't work with `React.createElement`

Comment: @fast-reflexes table will have either the first type or the second type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`React.FC` is essentially a function type with extra steps. And type parameter `P` in `React.FC<P>` goes in [negative/contravariant](https://www.stephanboyer.com/post/132/what-are-covariance-and-contravariance) position.

When you try to pass `image` prop into `CustomDataTable` it checks function compatibility and when it comes to arguments it check them in reverse direction. When you pass it an argument with type `React.FC<ProductImageProps>` it doesn't check whether `ProductImageProps` is assignable to `ProductImageProps | OrderImageProps` but whether `ProductImageProps | OrderImageProps` is assignable to `ProductImageProps`. That it's clearly not.

Changing your `image` prop type to `React.FC<ProductImageProps> | React.FC<OrderImageProps>` will get rid of previous `... is not assignable ...` error. But you'll get another error at `React.createElement` call site.

Now your new `props.image` has type `React.FC<ProductImageProps> | React.FC<OrderImageProps>`. But this type accepts only arguments of type `ProductImageProps & OrderImageProps`. i.e. having all required fields from *both* your prop types.

```ts
type PropsA = { a: string }
type PropsB = { b: string }

type A = (propsA: PropsA) => void
type B = (propsB: PropsB) => void

type AB = A | B

function fnFromAB(ab: AB): void { // ab has type (args: PropsA & PropsB) => void
    ab({ a: 'string' }) // error
    ab({ b: 'string' }) // error
    ab({ a: 'string ', b: 'string' }) // no error
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQAgvw)

The solution is to make type of `image` component depend on type of it's props. And since type of props depends on `list` flag you may rewrite your code as:

```ts
type CustomDataTableProps = {
    nameTag: string
    itemTag: string
    priceTag: string
    categoryTag: string
    dateTag: string
    actionsTag: string
} & ({
    image: React.FC<OrderImageProps>
    list: true
} | {    
    image: React.FC<ProductImageProps>
    list: false
})
    
const CustomDataTable: React.FC<CustomDataTableProps> = (props: CustomDataTableProps) => {
    const cartItems: ICartItem[] = useSelector((state: RootState): ICartItem[] => (state.cart.cartItems));
    const sampleData = sampleProducts.map((product: ICartItem) => {

    const image = props.list
        ? React.createElement(props.image, { orders: cartItems })
        : React.createElement(props.image, { src: product.src })

    return {
        image,
        // more data are in here
    };
}
```

Unfortunately you'll have to duplicate `React.createElement` call since `props.image` has different types in each of the arms of ternary operator.

You may cut some corners with type assertions ofcourse. But for the cost of type safety. As usual.

Comment: This is a good answer! The technique is called [discriminating union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions)

Comment: This is a great answer, explains everything needed. Thank you very much.